# Finding uniquely decodable codes

Tags: algorithm, encoding, character-encoding, compression

Which of the following codes are uniquely decodable?

`code 1    code 2    code 3   code 4
A     0         0          1       1
B     100       1         01      01
C     10       00        001     001
D     11       11       0001     000`

For those that are uniquely decodeable, give the encoding of 1000000000000

/*********************************/

So I have found that code 3 and 4 are prefix free and instantaneously decodable.  It's easy to give the encoding with code 4 as ADDDD, but I'm lost how I would do it for the third one since it doesn't seem to be able to match up to the string at all.  Am I wrong somehow that code 3 is uniquely decodable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code 3 is uniquely decodable, but it is not complete. Therefore you can come up with sequences of bits that are not decodable with Code 3. E.g. `0000`. In fact, you could make the code complete by adding the code `0000` for, say, `E`.

Code 4 on the other hand is complete, and so any sequence of bits can be decoded. (Though the sequence might end in the middle of a code.)